# PostgreSQL & C: How to print entire PostgreSQL result

Tags: c, postgresql

I'm using a C program to talk to a Postgres database.

I'd like to create a method that will allow the user to type a custom query in the C program and see the results printed as Postgres would print in its command line client `psql`.

For other queries, I was able to use functions I found in the documentation. The trouble is that these only work because I know the amount of columns I need and the appropriate headers etc.

For example:

```
void* executeCustomQuery(const char* query){
    PGresult* res = PQexec(conn, query);
    //print all entries
    printf(PRODUCTS_TABLE_HEADER);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < PQntuples(res); i++){
        printf("| %s | %s | %s |", PQgetvalue(res, i, 0), PQgetvalue(res, i, 1), PQgetvalue(res, i, 2)); 
    }
    PQclear(res);
}
```

I can't use this code if I don't know what I'm getting back.

Does anyone know of any way to print out the direct results from Postgres?

Comment: One of the nice "features" of Postgres is it's free/open source software - take a look at the `psql` code.

Comment: RTFM. Everything's there: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-SELECT-INFO

Comment: I found it shortly after posting. "RTM" would have done it though, no need for that "F"

Comment: It'd be nice if libpq exposed an easy "just print the query results" function. If you submitted one that formatted the query output to a filehandle (so you can pass stdout/stderr but don't have to) I'd be surprised if it wasn't accepted for future versions. Also, sometimes posting a patch is a great way to get someone to say "why don't you just use SecretUndocumentedFunctionNumber42"? Or say "ugh, that's a horrible way to do it, try <this patch>". Either way, win.

Comment: ... though it looks like such a function (`PQprint`) already exists. What about that doesn't meet your needs?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding the method `PQfname()` which gives me the column names of the table.
Using this I'm able to reconstruct the table with some for loops. It's not exactly what I was looking for but it's worth posting.

```
PGresult* res = PQexec(conn, query);
    char headerPrint[500];
        strcpy(headerPrint, "|");
        int h;
        for (h = 0; h < PQnfields(res); h++){
                strcat(headerPrint, " ");
                strcat(headerPrint, PQfname(res, h));
                strcat(headerPrint, " |");
                if (h == PQnfields(res)-1){
                    strcat(headerPrint, "\n");
                }
        }
        printf("%s", headerPrint);
        //Print content
        int i;
        char resultPrint[500];
        strcpy(resultPrint, "|");
        for (i = 0; i < PQntuples(res); i++){
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < PQnfields(res); j++){
                strcat(resultPrint, " ");
                strcat(resultPrint, PQgetvalue(res, i, j));
                strcat(resultPrint, " |");
                //printf("%s %d %s", "Value of i is: ", i, "\n");
                //printf("%s %d %s", "Value of j is: ", j, "\n");
                //New line at the end
                if (j == PQnfields(res)-1){
                    strcat(resultPrint, "\n");
                }
            }
            printf("%s", resultPrint);
            strcpy(resultPrint, "|"); //Clear the current row and start over
        }
        PQclear(res);
```

Comment: Readers should also look at `PQprint` .